# python dataflow, setup is called but process is not

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a streaming python dataflow job. Because of some expensive setup, I implement `setup` method for my DoFn class. When I work it using DirectRunner everything works as expected. However, when I deploy this to dataflow (GCP), `process` is never called. I can confirm by looking at log, `setup` was finished succesfully but no log from `process` is called. What could be the reason?

Simplified code of my job:

```
class PredictionFn(beam.DoFn):
    def setup(self):
        # download data from remote server etc
        # ...

        logging.info('setup successful!')


    def process(self, element):
        (user_id, device_id) = element
        logging.info('process ' + user_id_hash)

        # more logic here...
        

def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--subscription',
        required=True,
        help=(
            'Input PubSub subscription of the form '
            '"projects/<PROJECT>/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION>"'))
    parser.add_argument(
        '--bigtable_instance',
        help='The Bigtable instance ID',
        default='devices-metadata')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--bigtable_table',
        help='The Bigtable table ID in the instance.',
        default='device-profiles')
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    # We use the save_main_session option because DoFn's in this
    # workflow rely on global context (e.g., a module imported at module level).
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session
    pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True
    project_id = pipeline_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).project

    logging.info('initializing pipeline: %s', known_args.subscription)
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        users = (p
            | "ReadEvents" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.subscription, with_attributes=False)
            | "ExtractUser" >> beam.ParDo(ExtractUserId())
            | beam.ParDo(AddTimestampFn())
            | beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(5, 0))
            | beam.Distinct())

        predictions = (users
            | 'Predict' >> (beam.ParDo(PredictionFn())))

        _ = (predictions
            | 'PredictionToRowUpdate' >> beam.ParDo(CreateRowFn())
            | WriteToBigTable(
                project_id=project_id,
                instance_id=known_args.bigtable_instance,
                table_id=known_args.bigtable_table))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger('elasticsearch').setLevel(logging.WARN)
    run()
```

Comment: Can you see elements being added to the ParDo? You can see it in the UI. I suspect elements being dropped in the window because they are late or in the Distinct

Comment: I just tried running job again and here is what I got https://prnt.sc/vnkmka https://prnt.sc/vnkmny https://prnt.sc/vnkmre
Looks like distinct doesn't return any item? How it could be possible?

Comment: The window is applied when there's aggregation, so if the elements are late, they are going to be dropped in in the window step. Do you see any `droppedDueToLateness` (you can see this in the UI or in Metrics Explorer)? Checking your code you have windows of 5 seconds, is this what you want? It seems a rather short window, maybe try using at least a 1minute window.

Comment: Oh. Since job was broken with other reason we have a huge backlog in pubsub. So I guess all elements we get are late.

I thought window is more like "process elements in every X seconds" but I guess my understanding was wrong. Is there are way to allow old entry but make it flush every X seconds?

Comment: i cannot seem to find droppedDueToLateness in metrics explorer or ui

Comment: You could either add `allowed_lateness` very high so even very old elements can fall in an old window or maybe try a global window with a repeating trigger. Anyhow, I would suggest to increase the size of the window, 5 seconds is rather low and if you have a high allowed lateness, you'd end up having millions of windows. I will make an official answer tomorrow so other users can see it.

Comment: What about `droppedDueToClosedWindow`? Anyhow, try creating a new pipeline with a new subscription just to check everything is fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224913/discussion-between-kazuki-and-inigo).